# Ubuntu Server - Internet connectivity issue, empty /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, server

I manage a server which hosts a few applications. It's running on a VM and I access via SSH.

OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS

Everything was working fine until today, my scripts can't access WAN.
(Can still SSH in)

I can ping out:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.212.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams16s21-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=5.26 ms
64 bytes from ams16s21-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=5.54 ms
```

DNS resolves fine:

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.212.206
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4009:80a::200e
```

Can't get anything with curl:

```
$ curl -v https://www.google.com
*   Trying 216.58.212.196:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4009:80a::2004:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4009:80a::2004: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4009:80a::2004:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4009:80a::2004: Network is unreachable
```

---

```
$ ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:fd:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c2:db:08:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

---

```
$ ip route list
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.14 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.14 
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.14 metric 100
```

---

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

---

```
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:c2:db:08:92  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:fd32  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:01:fd:32  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 35862  bytes 5205966 (5.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4364  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3838  bytes 1097697 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8663  bytes 1793628 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8663  bytes 1793628 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Could this be a problem:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

(EMPTY)

---

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: "Could this be a problem:
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces  (EMPTY)" No, because networking in server edition is now managed by netplan. What does this tell us? `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks,
`network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2`

Comment: `eth0` is usually NOT the proper definition for a device on system - what does `ip -4 link list` show (so we can ID what the actual network interface name is and help you fix the config)?

Comment: Okay, I get the same as with `ip link list` as above.

Comment: It was an external firewall issue   Thanks, for your efforts!